# проблема переноса обычного проекта Laravel с опен сервера на хостинг

Tags: laravel, хостинг

уважаемые знатоки!

Я столкнулся с проблемой переноса дефолтного проекта Laravel (сделанного на OpenServer домашней машине) на удалённый хостинг.

Перенос делал по гайду из видео: содержимое папки public в public_html, остальное просто в папку (называется project).

В файле index.php изменил пути [image: добавил путь к тесовой папке с фреймворком].

Получил ошибку на домене:

ErrorException (E_WARNING)
file_put_contents(C:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\project\project\storage\framework/sessions/FYq9CUUKlHh0uIgu1VlRQ50ylyhml2jj8pS3aT61): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Понимаю, что каким-то образом дублировался путь project. Но не знаю что менять и где..и почему так сложно оказалось перенести даже пустой проект.

p.s. Проект абсолютно пустой тестовый (выводится лишь welcome.blade.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ErrorException (E_WARNING) file_put_contents(C:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\project\project\storage\framework/sessions/FYq9CUUKlHh0uIgu1VlRQ50ylyhml2jj8pS3aT61): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Вас не смущает указанный путь ? Похоже , что дополнительно в кэше остались старые пути к директориям. Попробуйте в первую очередь через команды **artisan** очистить кэш :

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Для выполнение данных действий у Вас должен быть доступ **ssh** к Вашему аккаунту на общем сервере.

Не думаю , что стоит проводить манипуляции с изменением директории , Вы можете разместить костяк проекта в **public_html**  и запросить у хостера изменение основной директории на **public_html/public** . Как правило , нормальные хостинги должны это сделать . Также , можно через .**htaccess** попросту настроить **rewrite** на директорию **public** :

```
DirectoryIndex /public/index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: завтра попробую ваш способ! спасибо за совет!

Comment: ОК , если возникнут доп. сложности - готов помочь с разворачиванием проекта.

Comment: сложности только начинаются! потому что я сделал сайт на ларе полноценный* ну так скажем тестовый) и когда я его закинул на хост получил ошибку 500...после чего понял, что надо решать вопрос поэтапно и начать с залива обычного проекта. Для меня это очень тяжело..хотя бы потому что 10 000 файлов в одном проекте перезаливать на фтп это дело такое(

Comment: аж руки опускаются после такого...

Comment: папку vendor также тащите с собой ?

Comment: навреное..не надо было..сейчас прочитаю

Comment: Ошибка ErrorException (E_WARNING) file_put_contents(C:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\project\project\storage\framework/sessions/FYq9CUUKlHh0uIgu1VlRQ50ylyhml2jj8pS3aT61): failed to open stream: No such file or directory повторилась

Comment: Свяжись со мной в телеге , если ещё актуально. @korkoshko